# Проблема в 11 строке Memory Error - Python3

Tags: python

Я относительный новичок, поэтому прошу объяснить в чем заключается ошибка и почему она возникает.
Вот код:

```
print("Hello, dear user")
n = int(input())
r = list(input())



for i in r:
    goodl = list()
    col = r.count(i)
    while col != 1:
        goodl.append(i)
        if col == 1:
            continue

print(goodl)
```

Comment: Что должен решать ваш код? Как звучит сама задача? И предоставьте пример входных данных

Comment: Программа должна убирать из списка  неповторяющиеся элементы. Входные данные: на первой строке любое число, не важно, на второй -     1 2 3 4 4    например

Comment: Ответ с решением задачи обновлён, проверяйте

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот в этом моменте у вас логическая ошибка:

```py
while col != 1:
    goodl.append(i)
    if col == 1:
        continue
```

Блок `if` не нужен вовсе, т.к. переход на следующую итерацию произойдёт в любом случае

Кроме того, у вас используется цикл `while col != 1`, но `col` внутри цикла не меняется. Это бесконечный цикл. А поскольку в цикле вы не просто выполняете, например, вывод на экран, а дополняете список, со временем размер списка увеличивается, как следствие - и количество памяти, которое он занимает, и в конце концов вызывается ошибка `Memory error`.

На вопрос о том, почему вызывается ошибка, я ответил. Опишите, что должна решать ваша задача, и я помогу вам исправить эту ошибку

#### Upd: решение поставленной задачи

```py
print("Hello, dear user")
n = int(input('N > '))
r = list(input('R > '))
goodl = [element for element in r if r.count(element) > 1]
print(goodl)
```

Входные данные:

```py
N > 5
R > 1 2 3 4 1 5 3
```

Результат

```py
['1', ' ', ' ', '3', ' ', ' ', '1', ' ', ' ', '3']
```

Если нужно, чтобы пробелы в список не добавлялись, то 4 строка выглядит так:

```py
goodl = [element for element in r if r.count(element) > 1 and element != ' ']
```

Для тех же входных данных результат:

```py
['1', '3', '1', '3']
```

Если `R` может иметь вид `123 4 123 4 2 4`, т.е. элементы могут быть не из одного символа, подойдёт такой вариант:

```py
print("Hello, dear user")
n = int(input('N > '))
r = input('R > ').split(' ')
goodl = [element for element in r if r.count(element) > 1]
print(goodl)
```

Входные данные:

```py
N > 5
R > 123 4 123 4 2 4
```

Результат:

```py
['123', '4', '123', '4', '4']
```

Comment: Спасибо за Ваше время)

Comment: @TheGloomDreamer, не за что)